# Using LIKE operator with stored procedure parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, sql-like

I have a stored procedure that uses the `LIKE` operator to search for a truck location among some other parameters

```
   @location nchar(20),
   @time time,
   @date date
AS
   select 
       DonationsTruck.VechileId, Phone, Location, [Date], [Time]
   from 
       Vechile, DonationsTruck
    where 
       Vechile.VechileId = DonationsTruck.VechileId
       and (((Location like '%'+@location+'%') or (Location like '%'+@location) or (Location like @location+'%') ) or [Date]=@date or [Time] = @time)
```

I null the other parameters and search by location only but it always returns no results even when I used the full name of the location

Comment: To correctly handle NULL values you need to check for it explicitly, e.g. `( [Date] = @Date or @Date is NULL )`.  By the way, you only need to check for `'%' + @location + '%'`, the other two location tests are redundant.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: Avoir using OR as much as you can as it will degrade considerably your performance.  If possible use the  "In" clause instead.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your datatype for `@location nchar(20)` should be `@location nvarchar(20)`, since nChar has a fixed length (filled with Spaces).
If Location is nchar too you will have to convert it:

```
 ... Cast(Location as nVarchar(200)) like '%'+@location+'%' ...
```

To enable nullable parameters with and `AND` condition just use IsNull or Coalesce for comparison, which is not needed in your example using `OR`.

e.g. if you would like to compare for Location AND Date and Time.

```
@location nchar(20),
@time time,
@date date
as
select DonationsTruck.VechileId, Phone, Location, [Date], [Time]
from Vechile, DonationsTruck
where Vechile.VechileId = DonationsTruck.VechileId
and (((Location like '%'+IsNull(@location,Location)+'%')) and [Date]=IsNUll(@date,date) and [Time] = IsNull(@time,Time))
```

Comment: Location like '%'+IsNull(@location,Location)+'%') will return all records if location param is null, which might not be the behaviour wanted. the question is if there is no search criteria (if null location param considered no search criteria) passed, should the SP return everything or nothing? (please fix the comment restriction here, if putting the parameter with the @ symble, S.O. will think it's at someone :)

Answer (score 7):

I was working on same. Check below statement. Worked for me!!

---

```
SELECT * FROM [Schema].[Table] WHERE [Column] LIKE '%' + @Parameter + '%'
```

Comment: Works perfectly and as expected !

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_schemeallotment] (
    @SchemeName NVARCHAR (255) = ' ',
    @Ind INT = 0
)
AS
  BEGIN
      IF ( @Ind = 1 )
        BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM   schemeallotment
        END

      IF ( @Ind = 2 )
        BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM   schemeallotment
            WHERE  schemename LIKE '%' + @SchemeName + '%'
        END
  END

--exec sp_SchemeAllotment @Ind=2, @SchemeName='shree'
go
```

It is important to assign these variable like this:

```
(
    @SchemeName nvarchar (255) = ' ',
    @Ind int = 0
)
```

Comment: Your code looks very similar to that in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69448297/10871073). You should add some explanation as to how your answer is significantly different from the others.

Comment: ... although, I now notice that the other answer is from a user with the same username. Are you both the same person? If so, why two accounts and two answers?

Answer (score 0):

for mysql-  SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE columnanme LIKE '%'+ @location+'%';

for oracle - SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE columnanme LIKE '%'|| @location ||'%';

Answer (score -1):

```
...
WHERE ...
      AND (@Location is null OR (Location like '%' + @Location + '%'))
      AND (@Date is null OR (Date = @Date))
```

This way it is more obvious the parameter is not used when null.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
   CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_SchemeAllotment]
    (
    @SchemeName nvarchar (255)='',
    @Ind int=0
    )
    As 
    Begin
    if (@Ind = 1)
    begin
    SELECT * FROM SchemeAllotment
    End
    if (@Ind = 2)
    begin
    SELECT * FROM SchemeAllotment where SchemeName like '%'+ @SchemeName +'%'
    end
    End
    --exec sp_SchemeAllotment @Ind=2, @SchemeName='shree'
    GO
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The above condition for LIKE is wrong, you need to use LIKE command is
COL1 like '%@Variable%'

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: Using the SQL containing '%@Variable%' would require the literal string **@Variable** be within the matched result. The % will be used as wildcards, however @Variable is within the single quotes, so it will not be resolved to the passed value (because *it is within* the single quotes)

Answer (score -5):

EG : COMPARE TO VILLAGE NAME

```
ALTER PROCEDURE POSMAST
(@COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(50))
AS
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE 
village_name LIKE + @VILLAGE_NAME + '%';
```

Comment: you should like this code: LIKE '%' + @VILLAGE_NAME + '%'